# Excel reference to other sheet fails

Tags: windows, reference, excel-formula, excel-2007

### Error

When referencing from one sheet to another sheet within a workbook, while navigating to the target cells and ranges, a reference is placed in another cell in the first sheet, often with #REF in it. See details below.

### Questions

- How can I remove this bug?
- Or isn't it a bug an just a setting in Excel that I changed
  unintentionally?

I have tried to fix the error (see 'My fix failures' below). Currently I see no other option than completely reinstall my PC, but I am afraid the bug is in the old files.

### Details

Some of the actions that I have observed are (but not limited to):

- I'm entering a formula in a cell while navigating to the target cells
  or ranges. So far so good, but when I hit enter, the formula I
  entered appears in a different cell than the one I was entering the
  formula in, overwriting the original content.
- The reference seems to 'land' on a random cell, replacing an existing cell, but it seems to land in that same cell whenever I try to make a reference from a different cell in the same sheet and a different cell in the target sheet that I am referring to.
- Within the same sheet, I can not make a new reference to another sheet. When I remove the first reference and replace it with a new reference to another sheet, it 'lands' on a new cell. Oddly, there is a new reference in the target sheet as well.
- The error occurs while I am putting in

  - Normal references: ='sheet 2'!A7
  - Index references: =INDEX(Sheet2!$B$3:$F$7;Sheet1!B3;Sheet1!C3)
  - VLookup references: =VLOOKUP(B3;Sheet2!A3:F7;Sheet1!C3+1;0)
- It seems to occur in older files only. I just made a new file and could not reproduce the error.

  - The problem does not occur in Excel 2007 on my laptop while working in the same old files that show this problem on my desktop.

I fail to detect the system in the error.

### My fix failures

I have been experiencing this error for some time now and tried these options:

- Searching this forum and others, via Google a.o.
- Cleaning up the registry (CCleaner, Avira speed-up)
- Reparing Excel 2007 (Professional)
- Removing Office 2007, upgrading from Windows 7 to 10, reinstalling Office 2007

Comment: This behavior implies that excel does not recognize as valid references:
` sheet 2` in this formula ='sheet 2'!A7
Either `Sheet1` or `Sheet2` in this formula `=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$3:$F$7;Sheet1!B3;Sheet1!C3)`
Either `Sheet1` or `Sheet1` in this formula `=VLOOKUP(B3;Sheet2!A3:F7;Sheet1!C3+1;0)`

Comment: (Continuation) However when an user tries to enter a formula that refers to a `Sheet` that is not present in the `Workbook` where the formula is entered, Excel opens a dialog box for the user to select or point to an existing `Workbook` where the `Sheet` is trying to use is expected to exist. 1) What happens when you enter this formulas? 2) Are these formulas entered manually or with a Macro? 3) Where this formulas working before and now is when they are showing `#REF` as result?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm entering a formula in a cell while navigating to the target cells or ranges. So far so good, but when I hit enter, the formula I entered appears in a different cell than the one I was entering the formula in. I should have mentioned this detail.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot figure what it means "entering a formula in a cell while navigating to the target cell or ranges". Are you typing a formula and moving the cursor? Still missing answer to questions 1 & 3. Also have you check for Add-Ins and Event macros. Have you tried with only the workbook with the problem open. Have you tried with all macros inactive?

Comment: Sorry that I'm not clear and thanks for sticking to my problem. There are two ways of entering a formula: 1) typing the whole formula, including references and 2) typing '=' or  '= vlookup(" etc. and then using your cursor and mouse pointer to 'navigate' to the cell or range you want to reference in your formula. Option 1 works fine, option 2 does not work when I refer to another sheet in the workbook.

Comment: And I'm sorry, but I don not fully understand your question 1 and 2. I have only one workbook open. I work with several add-ins but they are on my laptop too (without a problem).

Comment: I just opened an old file and tried it with 'protect me from macro's' on and I experience the same problem there.

Comment: The problem does not occur in Excel 2007 on my laptop while working in the same old files that show this problem on my desktop.

Comment: Any chance of posting the problematic workbook...

Comment: Where can I post it?

Comment: Try using Google sheets, dropbox.com, etc

Comment: I can send it to you

Answer (score -1):

You can use INDIRECT("") formula to reference cells or named range in other worksheet

Comment: Thanks. I think it is a bug or wrong option in Excel though.

Comment: I have tried this, and it works, if not this then try to put your range from other sheet into an array by click on the formula bar and CTRL + ALT+ ENTER

Comment: I have no problem with the formula itself (it works fine on my laptop), the thing is that referencing to another worksheet in any formula fails. It is the referencing to other worksheets that fails by navigating during the formula editing (not typing the formula, this works fine).